# Backand queries, tables etc. not in sync, but actual data is

Tags: ionic2, backand

I'm having a weird issue with Backand. I created an app, a couple of tables, inserted data, and created a query using their web frontend. Integrated Backand in my Ionic2 app, worked great. A few hours later I added a couple of queries, and got the error message that the object doesn't exist when using the query. I changed the query I used successfully earlier, and got the same result as before the change - so the changes to my queries where not synced to the server (I'd assume). I added a field to a table I did this.backand.object.getList('items') before, but the field was missing. Strangely the data I am adding to the tables, or changing is correctly shown in both my app, and the web frontend.
In summary - data is the same in web frontend and my app, any changes to data model, or queries are shown in web frontend but not in the app.
Anyone has seen that before?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, 8 hours later everything is in sync. My query can be used in the app, changes to the data model are also seen by the app (through the API).